# JGraphT: Replacing subtree in a directed acyclic graph by another subtree

Tags: java, jgrapht

Let's assume I have the following two tree graphs:

```
     a                               i
   /    \                          /    \
  b      c                        j      k
 / \    / \                      / \    / \
d   e  f   g                    l   m  n   o
```

And I need to extract the subgraph `b` from the first graph and replace it in the second graph like this:

```
     i
   /    \
  j      b
 / \    / \
l   m  d   e
```

Is there any existing API in JGraphT to allow this?

Comment: A minimal working example would have been helpful. You'd also have to be a bit more precise as to what you exactly need. What are the characteristics of the input graphs? Are they trees (directed acyclic graphs)? What exactly is the replace operation supposed to do? Replace subtrees?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following answer is based on the following assumptions:

- both input graphs, `g1` and `g2` are acyclic directed graphs (trees)
- you want to replace a subtree in `g2` by a subtree in `g1`
- both `g1` and `g2` are vertex and edge disjoint, that is a vertex (edge) in `g1` does not appear in `g2` and vice versa.

JGraphT does not have a built-in method for subtree replacements, but it would be fairly simple to implement such method:

```
/**
* Replaces the subtree rooted in root2 in graph g2 with the subtree rooted in root1 in graph g1. Graph g1 is left
* unchanged.
* @param g1 first graph
* @param g2 second graph
* @param root1 root of subtree in first graph
* @param root2 root of subtree in second graph
* @param <V> vertex type
* @param <E> edge type
*/
public static <V,E> void replaceSubtree(Graph<V, E> g1, Graph<V, E> g2, V root1, V root2){
    //1. Add subtree under root1 to graph g2 as a disconnected component
    BreadthFirstIterator<V, E> bfs = new BreadthFirstIterator<>(g1,root1);
    g2.addVertex(bfs.next());
    while (bfs.hasNext()){
        V vertex=bfs.next();
        V parent=bfs.getParent(vertex);
        g2.addVertex(vertex);
        g2.addEdge(parent,vertex,bfs.getSpanningTreeEdge(vertex));
    }

    //2. Get the edge (object) between root2 and its parent. A special case occurs if root2 is also the root of g2
    // in which case it does not have a parent.
    E treeEdge = (g2.incomingEdgesOf(root2).isEmpty() ? null : g2.incomingEdgesOf(root2).iterator().next());
    V parent= (treeEdge == null ? null : Graphs.getOppositeVertex(g2, treeEdge, root2));

    //3. Remove subtree rooted in vertex k
    bfs = new BreadthFirstIterator<>(g2,root2);
    while(bfs.hasNext())
        g2.removeVertex(bfs.next());

    //4. Reconnect the two components
    if(parent != null)
        g2.addEdge(parent, root1, treeEdge);
}
```

Here's some test code:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Graph<String, DefaultEdge> g1 = new SimpleDirectedGraph<>(DefaultEdge.class);
    Graphs.addAllVertices(g1, Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"));
    g1.addEdge("a", "b");
    g1.addEdge("a", "c");
    g1.addEdge("b", "d");
    g1.addEdge("b", "e");
    g1.addEdge("c", "f");
    g1.addEdge("c", "g");

    Graph<String, DefaultEdge> g2 = new SimpleDirectedGraph<>(DefaultEdge.class);
    Graphs.addAllVertices(g2, Arrays.asList("i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o"));
    g2.addEdge("i", "j");
    g2.addEdge("i", "k");
    g2.addEdge("j", "l");
    g2.addEdge("j", "m");
    g2.addEdge("k", "n");
    g2.addEdge("k", "o");

    replaceSubtree(g1, g2, "b", "k");

    System.out.println(g2);
}
```

- `replaceSubtree(g1, g2, "b", "k");` gives: `([i, j, l, m, b, d, e], [(i,j), (j,l), (j,m), (b,d), (b,e), (i,b)])`
- `replaceSubtree(g1, g2, "b", "i");` gives: `([b, d, e], [(b,d), (b,e)])`